# Woocommerce product title is H2

Tags: woocommerce

I have this code in my single-product/title.php but the output is still a H2 tag. Anyone know where else this could be getting called from?

```
the_title( '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

I even put a copy of the file in my themes woocommerce directory but it still isn't working.

Comment: First flush cache by ctrl+F5. Then check your HTML DOM structure is updated. Code is correct only.

Comment: I have done that, It is still coming up <h2 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">Product Name</h2>

Comment: check you added templates under active theme directory.

Comment: It is in the right place.

Comment: I found the dang thing, For some reason it was under themes/Avada/templates/wc-single-title.php

Comment: It's wrong. It should be like this `\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\woocommerce\single-product\title.php`.

Comment: It should, but it wasnt. I edited the wc-single-title.php and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Avada and their curious way of templating WC, and the /templates/wc-single-title.php location worked perfectly